# load a fake debug symbol in gdb when debugging a stripped program

Tags: c, linux, gdb, x86-64, disassembly

I'm debugging a stripped program using `gdb`.

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007fffcb443650 in fooSnprintf () from ./install.so.1
```

I know that 3rd argument is the format sting:

```
(gdb) print (char*)$rdx
$9 = 0x7fffe8dd4050 "%u %s"
```

How do I make gdb show function args at breakpoint stop, like it does, when real debug symbols are loaded?

```
Breakpoint 1, fooSnprintf (a=0, b=0, fmt=0x40060a "%u %s") at test.c:3
```

I know about `hook-stop`, but it's global and will trigger on any breakpoint.

This works, but inconvenient:

```
define hook-stop
    if $rip == fooSnprintf
        print (char*)$rdx
    end
end
```

Comment: Is the program you try to debug your own program, or a third-party program? Is there no way to get a non-stripped version of the program? Or a core dump? If you have a core dump then you can copy it and debug the program locally using a non-stripped executable.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I wouldn't ask if I could do that

Answer (score 2):

You can associate commands with a particular breakpoint using the `commands` directive:

```
break fooSnprintf
commands
print (char*)$rdx
end
```

See [here](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Break-Commands.html) for more detail

Answer (score 1):

Made a fake source file.

```
[root@softiwarp-1 ~]# cat fooSnprintf.c
void padding() {
__asm__ volatile (
"\n nop"
"\n nop"
"\n nop"
"\n nop"
"\n nop"
"\n nop"
"\n nop"
"\n nop"
"\n nop"
"\n nop"
"\n nop"
"\n nop"
"\n nop"
"\n nop"
);
}

int fooSnprintf(void *a, void *b, char *fmt, ...) {
        return a && b && fmt;
}
```

Compiled a shared library with `-O2` (important, because with `-O0` gdb expects the function to put registers to stack). By trial and error selected a proper load address:

```
[root@joe ~]# gcc -fPIC -g -O2 -shared -o fooSnprintf.so fooSnprintf.c \
-Wl,-Ttext-segment=$(printf 0x%x $((0x00007fffcb443650 - 1392)))
```

Load

```
(gdb) symbol-file /root/fooSnprintf.so
Load new symbol table from "/root/fooSnprintf.so"? (y or n) y
Reading symbols from /root/fooSnprintf.so...done.
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Breakpoint 2, fooSnprintf (a=0x7fffc9ef0560, b=0xc8, fmt=0x7fffe8dd4050 "%u %s") at fooSnprintf.c:21
21              return a && b && fmt;
```